# ReactJS - react-select - multiple text color

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jquery-select2

I have been asked to have multiple text colours for a certain dropdown option something like this:

```
<select>
        <option>Test <span style="color:red;">New</span></option>
</select>
```

Now obviously this will not work for HTML select, but will I be able to do something like this with react-select. If not can someone suggest an alternative?

**UPDATE**

I also tried with select2, didn't work, is what I am trying to do not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with select2, here's the idea on how to do this with both templateResult & templateSelection

```js
var data = [{
  id: 0,
  text: '<span>Test <span style="color:red;">New</span></span>'
}];

$("select").select2({
  data: data,
  templateResult: function(d) {
    return $(d.text);
  },
  templateSelection: function(d) {
    return $(d.text);
  },

})
```

```css
.select2-dropdown {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select></select>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3z2txkba/